# How to silently upgrade EmEditor

Tags: emeditor

I would like to automatically roll out the latest version of EmEditor using a script, so it will update any previous installed version, without prompting the user to select Next, Next, Finsh, etc. and keep all the existing settings.

I know "msiexec /i emed64_xx_y_z.msi" should work with some switches, but could you advise on the correct switches to do this silently (and ideally provide a "Completed" progress at the end only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

`msiexec /i "(...path...)emed64_x.x.x.msi" /q MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1`

Reference: [How can I install EmEditor without displaying dialog boxes?](http://www.emeditor.org/en/faq_setup_setup_quiet.html)

Comment: Thanks Yutaka - this works but the problem is I can't run msiexec without admin (or elevated) rights. On locked down machines (where the user doesn't have any admin rights) this is not available.However, this is a Windows issue, not EmEditor, so I have marked the answer complete.

Comment: I don't believe `msiexec` needs to be elevated to be run because you can install EmEditor per user without admin rights or elevated. It sounds that Windows Group Policy causes this issue. Can you check your group policy?